# Custom UI Editor For Microsoft Office

Tags: xml, vba, excel, ribbonx

I want to add one more group in addition to what I have created. But I don't know how to code it.

Well, am a beginner in Custom U.I. Editor For Microsoft Office. (Excel Customized Ribbon Making)

With this code, I have created several menus. But, how can I add more than one group on the same tab. Can anyone help me in this regards.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab
                id="Tab1"
                label="QUICK FIX">
                <group
                    id="Group1"
                    label="Time Saving Tools">
                    <menu
                        id="Menu1"
                        image="Home"
                        label="Menu"
                        size="large">
                        <menu
                            id="Menu2"
                            label="Add New"
                            imageMso="TablePropertiesDialog">
                            <button
                                id="Button01"
                                label="1. Add a new sheet with Current Date"
                                imageMso="ExportExcel"
                                onAction="AddSheetCurrentDate" />
                            <button
                                id="Button02"
                                label="2. Add a Calendar Sheet with user given period"
                                imageMso="CreateTable"
                                onAction="CalendarMake" />
                            <button
                                id="Button03"
                                label="3. Add a sheet with This Year Calendar"
                                imageMso="ViewAllProposals"
                                onAction="ThisYearCalendar" />
                            <button
                                id="Button04"
                                label="4. Create Table of Contents"
                                imageMso="FunctionsLogicalInsertGallery"
                                onAction="TableOfContent" />
                        </menu>
                        <menu
                            id="Menu3"
                            label="Visibility and Protection"
                            imageMso="DatabaseSetLogonSecurity">
                            <button
                                id="Button05"
                                label="1. Make this sheet very hidden"
                                imageMso="RelationshipsHideTable"
                                onAction="ActiveSheetVeryHidden" />
                            <button
                                id="Button06"
                                label="2. Show all very hidden sheets"
                                imageMso="SubformMenu"
                                onAction="ShowVeryHiddenShts" />
                            <button
                                id="Button07"
                                label="3. Unhide All Sheets"
                                imageMso="PersonaStatusOnline"
                                onAction="UnhideAllHiddenShts" />
                            <button
                                id="Button08"
                                label="4. Protect All Sheets"
                                imageMso="Lock"
                                onAction="Protect_All_Shts" />
                            <button
                                id="Button09"
                                label="5. Un-Protect All Sheets"
                                imageMso="FileCompatibilityChecker"
                                onAction="Unprotect_All_Shts" />
                            <button
                                id="Button10"
                                label="6. List All Un-Protected Sheets"
                                imageMso="Numbering"
                                onAction="ListAllUnprotectedShts" />
                            <button
                                id="Button11"
                                label="7. List All Visible and Hidden Sheets"
                                imageMso="DatasheetColumnLookup"
                                onAction="List_all_visible_and_hidden_shts" />
                            <button
                                id="Button12"
                                label="8. Lock Cells Containing Formula"
                                imageMso="FileLinksToFiles"
                                onAction="LockCellsWithFormula" />
                            <button
                                id="Button13"
                                label="9. Set Custom Zoom % For All Sheets"
                                imageMso="ZoomPrintPreviewExcel"
                                onAction="SetCustomZoomForAllShts" />
                        </menu>
                        <menu
                            id="Menu4"
                            label="Columns and Rows"
                            imageMso="TablePropertiesDialog">
                            <button
                                id="Button14"
                                label="1. Auto Fit All Rows in this Worksheet"
                                imageMso="GridlinesGallery"
                                onAction="AutoFitAllRows1" />
                            <button
                                id="Button15"
                                label="2. Auto Fit All Columns in this Worksheet"
                                imageMso="RelationshipsHideTable"
                                onAction="AutoFitColumnsInActiveSheet" />
                            <button
                                id="Button16"
                                label="3. Delete All Blank Columns"
                                imageMso="OmsDelete"
                                onAction="DeleteBlankColums" />
                            <button
                                id="Button17"
                                label="4. Delete All Blank Rows"
                                imageMso="OmsDelete"
                                onAction="DeleteBlankRows" />
                        </menu>
                        <menu
                            id="Menu5"
                            label="Apply Formula On Cells and Comments"
                            imageMso="ActionInsert">
                            <button
                                id="Button18"
                                label="1. Insert Formula On Selected Cells PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="AutoSum"
                                onAction="InsertFormulaOnSelectedCells" />
                            <button
                                id="Button19"
                                label="2. Insert Comments (Multiple Cells) PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="WebServerDiscussions"
                                onAction="InsertCommentsOnSelection" />
                            <button
                                id="Button20"
                                label="3. Highlight Cells with Comments PS:(No Undo) "
                                imageMso="ObjectEffectGlowGallery"
                                onAction="HighlightCommentOnCells" />
                            <button
                                id="Button21"
                                label="4. Highlight Duplicated Values on the Selected Range PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="ConditionalFormattingHighlightCompareColumns"
                                onAction="HighlightDuplicatedValuesOnRange" />
                            <button
                                id="Button22"
                                label="5. Change Comment Box Appearance in this Sheet PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="AppointmentColorDialog"
                                onAction="ChangeCommentBoxColorOnThisSheet" />
                            <button
                                id="Button23"
                                label="6. Replace Blank Cells With Zero on the Selected Range PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="O"
                                onAction="ReplaceBlankCellsWithZeroOnSelection" />
                        </menu>
                        <menu
                            id="Menu6"
                            label="Text Utilities"
                            imageMso="FontSchemes">
                            <button
                                id="Button24"
                                label="1. Convert Text To Lower Case PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="ReplaceDialog"
                                onAction="ConvertTextToLowerCase" />
                            <button
                                id="Button25"
                                label="2. Convert Text To Upper Case PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="SlideThemesGallery"
                                onAction="ConvertTextToUpperCase" />
                            <button
                                id="Button26"
                                label="3. Convert Text To Proper Case PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="FontSchemes"
                                onAction="ConvertTextToProperCase" />
                            <button
                                id="Button27"
                                label="4. Remove all Numbers from the Selected Cells PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="InterconnectDeleteCard"
                                onAction="RemoveAllNumbersFromSelection" />
                            <button
                                id="Button28"
                                label="5. Remove all Text from the Selected Cells PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="WatermarkRemove"
                                onAction="RemoveAllTextFromSelectedRange" />
                            <button
                                id="Button29"
                                label="6. Convert Text Number to Number Format PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="_1"
                                onAction="ConvertTextNumbersToNumberFormt" />
                        </menu>
                        <menu
                            id="Menu8"
                            label="Prefix and Suffix"
                            imageMso="ReviewCompareTwoVersions">
                            <button
                                id="Button30"
                                label="1. Prefix to Existing Data PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="MailMergeGoToNextRecord"
                                onAction="PrefixToExistingLeft" />
                            <button
                                id="Button31"
                                label="2. Suffix to Existing Data PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="MailMergeGoToPreviousRecord"
                                onAction="SuffixToExistingRight" />
                        </menu>
                        <menu
                            id="Menu9"
                            label="Clean Up!"
                            imageMso="ControlToolboxOutlook">
                            <button
                                id="Button32"
                                label="1. Remove Leading and Trailing Spaces in this Sheet PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="AsianLayoutMenu"
                                onAction="RemoveLeadingTrailingSpacesInActiveSht" />
                            <button
                                id="Button33"
                                label="2. Delete Unused Formats in this Sheet PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="ControlActiveX"
                                onAction="DeleteUnusedFormatsActiveSheet" />
                            <button
                                id="Button34"
                                label="3. Delete Unused Formats in this Workbook PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="CoverPageRemove"
                                onAction="DeleteUnusedFormatsAllWorkSheets" />
                            <button
                                id="Button35"
                                label="4. Clear Print Area in this Workbook PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="MasterDocumentUnlinkSubdocument"
                                onAction="ClearPrintAreaInAllShts" />
                            <button
                                id="Button36"
                                label="5. Clear All Hyperlinks in this Worksheet PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="HyperlinkRemove"
                                onAction="RemoveAllHyperlinksThisSheet" />
                            <button
                                id="Button37"
                                label="6. Remove all Styles not in use. PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="HyperlinkRemove"
                                onAction="RemoveStylesNotInUse" />
                            <button
                                id="Button38"
                                label="7. Reduce Size of This Workbook. PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="UpgradeWorkbook"
                                onAction="ReduceSizeOfWorkbook" />
                            <button
                                id="Button39"
                                label="8. Delete all Blank Sheets. PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="CoverPageRemove"
                                onAction="DeleteAllBlankWorkShts" />
                        </menu>
                        <menu
                            id="Menu10"
                            label="Sort"
                            imageMso="SortDialog">
                            <button
                                id="Button40"
                                label="1. Sort all Worksheets Alphabetically. PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="SortUp"
                                onAction="SortAllWorkSheetsAlphabetically" />
                            <button
                                id="Button41"
                                label="2. Sort all Worksheets by Colour. PS:(No Undo)"
                                imageMso="ViewBackToColorView"
                                onAction="SortWorkSheetsByColor" />
                        </menu>
                    </menu>
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Have you tried adding more than one `<group>...</group>` section?  If you've done some research, please share examples of what you've tried so far.  Also, see the [tour] as well as "[mcve]" and also the [Topics FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Dear Ashleedawg, Actually, I dont know where to place these two. Can you please guide?

Comment: Yeah, I told author the same thing, but... he doesn't wish to make localization :(

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest [Ribbon XML Editor](http://novikov.gq/counter_fd/counter_fd.php?file=ribbonxmleditor) by Maksim Novikov, but, alas, its interface is in Russian language. However, I think, it's not that hard to get around with it.

#### UPDATE

I contacted with program's author and offered English localization, but, to my chagrin, he declined this offer.

Comment: I'm russian, and (IMO) russian interface is not a good idea for such a tool:) Anyway, the two languages are mixed here.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up the XML in your question (using [XMLBeautifier](http://xmlbeautifier.com/)) so it is more organized, standardized, and easier to read.

I also added a tag to your question [ribbonx](/questions/tagged/ribbonx), which is another place to check for assistance with Office Ribbon XML.

I have not used *"Custom UI Editor For Microsoft Office"* but if this is a 3rd-Party application, I'd suggest seeing the developer's documentation or website for further information, however **I would *assume*** that you would add another group with standard XML form:

Something like:

```
<customUI…>
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab…>
                <group…>
                    <menu…>
                        <button…/>
                        <button…/>
                        <button…/>
                    </menu>
                    <menu…>
                        <button…/>
                        <button…/>
                        <button…/>
                    </menu>
                </group>
                <group…>
                    <menu…>
                        <button…/>
                        <button…/>
                        <button…/>
                    </menu>
                    <menu…>
                        <button…/>
                        <button…/>
                        <button…/>
                    </menu>
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

It might be a good idea to learn the basics of XML notation before diving into a custom UI.

- [Getting Started with XML Programming](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/norm/part1/getstart1.html)
- W3Schools: [XML Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/)
- [XML Well-formedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling)

Advanced Ribbon customization may require C# and/or Visual Studio:

- [How to: Get Started Customizing the Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608616.aspx)
- [Custom Ribbon UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf08984t.aspx#Ribbon)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx)